# My bitlocker .bek file no longer works after hybernate

Tags: usb, motherboard, hibernate, bitlocker

I changed motheboard temporarily. The original motherboard is being fixed.

I shut down my computer and restart just fine.

Microsoft ask for activation however, it isn't such a big deal. I can still use the computer and within 2 weeks the motherboard will be fixed anyway.

Then my bro asked me to dinner. I tried to power off the computer but in hurry couldn't find the power button. So I found other way to hibernate the computer. Basically I just hibernate instead of shut down.

Then, when the computer restart, it ask me for bitlocker password.

At first I thought the USB didn't work or the data in flash disk corrupt. My bro brought the USB to his computer and saw that the data was there. I also have copy of .bek file. I, however, do not have recovery key.

Basically I cannot access any of my main computer at all because of this.

Is there a way to "disable" hibernate mode and make the computer restart like usual? May be disabling the bitlocker?

I hybernate just fine in old motherboard. But the old motherboard is being fixed and I need access to my main computer fast. Most important data is in the cloud. But well, all my 1TB data will be gone. I need to reset windows and stuff.

The .bek file is there in the flash disk. It simply doesn't work.

To repeat. I am always able to restart and shut down computer and get back in shape easily. However, if I hibernate, I can't get back in.

Comment: If I were to guess, the reason it's not working, is because the TPM module is different.  Without the recovery you are up the creek without a paddles

Comment: I do not use TPM. I am using flash disk. Also somehow it works after I enter set up bios before coming in. An alternative is to restart to safe mode I guess.

Comment: If it works that means you can disable bitlocker then enable it again